# Python lexical analysis - logical line & compound statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-internals, bnf

So I understand that:

> The end of a logical line is represented by the token NEWLINE

This means the way Python's grammar is defined the only way to end a logical line is with a `\n` token.

The same goes for physical lines (rather an EOL, which is the EOL of the platform you're using when writing the file but nevertheless converted to a universal `\n` by Python.

A logical line can or cannot be equivalent to one or more physical lines, but usually it's one, and most of the times it's one if you write clean code.

In the sense that:

```
foo = 'some_value'  # 1 logical line = 1 physical  
foo, bar, baz = 'their', 'corresponding', 'values'  # 1 logical line = 1 physical
some_var, another_var = 10, 10; print(some_var, another_var); some_fn_call()

# the above is still still 1 logical line = 1 physical line
# because ; is not a terminator per se but a delimiter
# since Python doesn't use EBNF exactly but rather a modified form of BNF

# p.s one should never write code as the last line, it's just for educational purposes
```

Without showing examples of how 1 logical is equivalent to > 1 physical, **my question is the following part from the docs**:

> Statements cannot cross logical line boundaries except where NEWLINE
>   is allowed by the syntax (e.g., between statements in compound
>   statements)

But what does this even mean? I understand the list of the compound statements, be them: **if, while, for,** etc. they are all made up of one or multiple **clauses** and each **clause**, in turn is made up of **a header** and **a suite**.
The **suite** is made up of one or multiple **statements**, let's take an example to be more specific:

So the **if statement** is something like this according to the grammar **(excluding the elifs and else clauses)**:

```
if_stmt ::=  "if" expression ":" suite
```

where the suite and its subsequent statements:

```
suite         ::=  stmt_list NEWLINE | NEWLINE INDENT statement+ DEDENT
statement     ::=  stmt_list NEWLINE | compound_stmt
stmt_list     ::=  simple_stmt (";" simple_stmt)* [";"]
```

so this means that if you want you can choose (given by "|") your suite to be 1 of 2 ways:

1. on the same line:

   **disadvantages**: not pythonic and you cannot have another compound statement that introduces a new block (like a func def, another if, etc)

   **advatanges**: one liner I guess

example:

```
if 'truthy_string': foo, bar, baz = 1, 2, 3; print('whatever'); call_some_fn();
```

2. introduce a new block:

   **advantages**: all, and the proper way to do it

example:

```
if 'truthy_value':
    first_stmt = 5
    second_stmt = 10
    a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
    func_call()
    result = inception(nested(calls(one_param), another_param), yet_another))
```

but I don't see how

> Statements cannot cross logical line boundaries except where NEWLINE
>   is allowed by the syntax

What I see above is a **suite**, which is a **block of code** controlled by the **if clause**, and in turn, that **suite**, is made up of logical, independent lines (statements), where each logical line is one physical line (coincidentally). I don't see how one logical line can cross the boundaries (which basically is just a fancy word for the end, the limit, which is newline), I don't see how one statement can cross those boundaries and span into the next statement, or maybe I'm really confused and have everything mixed up, but if someone can please explain.

Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: I split lines in python 2 with a backslash at the end of the first part/line

Comment: I'm sorry but what does this have to do with my question? also please note that the recommended way is against using backslashes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Pythons grammar

Fortunately there is a [Full Grammar specification](https://docs.python.org/reference/grammar.html) in the Python documentation.

A statement is defined in that specification as:

```
stmt: simple_stmt | compound_stmt
```

And a logical line is delimited by `NEWLINE` (that's not in the specification but based on your question).

### Step-by-step

Okay, let's go through this, what's the specification for a

#### `simple_stmt`:

```
simple_stmt: small_stmt (';' small_stmt)* [';'] NEWLINE
small_stmt: (expr_stmt | del_stmt | pass_stmt | flow_stmt |
             import_stmt | global_stmt | nonlocal_stmt | assert_stmt)
```

Okay now it goes into several different paths and it probably doesn't make sense to go through all of them separately but based on the specification a `simple_stmt` *could* cross logical line boundaries *if* any of the `small_stmt`s contains a `NEWLINE` (currently they *don't* but *could*).

Apart from that only theoretical possibility there is actually the

#### `compound_stmt`:

```
compound_stmt: if_stmt | while_stmt | for_stmt | try_stmt | with_stmt | funcdef | classdef | decorated | async_stmt
[...]
if_stmt: 'if' test ':' suite ('elif' test ':' suite)* ['else' ':' suite]
[...]
suite: simple_stmt | NEWLINE INDENT stmt+ DEDENT
```

I picked only the `if` statement and `suite` because it already suffices. The `if` statement *including* `elif` and `else` and all of the content in these is **one statement** (a compound statement). And because it may contain `NEWLINE`s (if the `suite` isn't just a `simple_stmt`) it already fulfills the requirement of "a statement that crosses logical line boundaries".

### An example `if` (schematic):

```
if 1:
    100
    200
```

would be:

```
if_stmt
|---> test        --> 1
|---> NEWLINE
|---> INDENT
|---> expr_stmt   --> 100
|---> NEWLINE
|---> expr_stmt   --> 200
|---> NEWLINE
|---> DEDENT
```

And all of this belongs to the if statement (and it's not just a block "controlled" by the `if` or `while`, ...).

### The same `if` with [`parser`](https://docs.python.org/library/parser.html), [`symbol`](https://docs.python.org/library/symbol.html#module-symbol) and [`token`](https://docs.python.org/library/token.html#module-token)

A way to visualize that would be using the built-in `parser`, `token` and `symbol` modules (really, I haven't known about this modules before I wrote the answer):

```
import symbol
import parser
import token

s = """
if 1:
    100
    200
"""
st = parser.suite(s)

def recursive_print(inp, level=0):
    for idx, item in enumerate(inp):
        if isinstance(item, int):
            print('.'*level, symbol.sym_name.get(item, token.tok_name.get(item, item)), sep="")
        elif isinstance(item, list):
            recursive_print(item, level+1)
        else:
            print('.'*level, repr(item), sep="")

recursive_print(st.tolist())
```

Actually I cannot explain most of the `parser` result but it shows (if you remove a lot of unnecessary lines) that the `suite` including it's newlines really belongs to the `if_stmt`. Indentation represents the "depth" of the parser at a specific point.

```
file_input
.stmt
..compound_stmt
...if_stmt
....NAME
....'if'
....test
.........expr
...................NUMBER
...................'1'
....COLON
....suite
.....NEWLINE
.....INDENT
.....stmt
...............expr
.........................NUMBER
.........................'100'
.......NEWLINE
.....stmt
...............expr
.........................NUMBER
.........................'200'
.......NEWLINE
.....DEDENT
.NEWLINE
.ENDMARKER
```

That could probably be made much more beautiful but I hope it serves as illustration even in it's current form.

Comment: what an awesome explanation, all clear now, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's simpler than you think. A compound statement is considered a single statement, even though it may have other statements inside. Quoting the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html):

> Compound statements contain (groups of) other statements; they affect or control the execution of those other statements in some way. **In general, compound statements span multiple lines**, although in simple incarnations a whole compound statement may be contained in one line.

For example,

```
if a < b:
    do_thing()
    do_other_thing()
```

is a single `if` statement occupying 3 logical lines. That's how a statement can cross logical line boundaries.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I got it eventually, the problem was that I wasn't seeing the if statement as a whole, but rather as independent simple statements, I was thinking in logical lines rather than statements...so in the sense that... I was thinking, man how can it be possible to ever make a logical line span into the next, well that can't be possible since when you hit enter and add the NEWLINE token, the logical line ends...and that is still valid, but a compound statement as a whole, spans over multiple logical lines, crossing the boundaries of a single logical line..